# How do I change cellular data DNS servers to OpenDNS?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an iPhone that I want to setup using [OpenDNS's FamilySearch DNS servers](http://www.opendns.com/home-solutions/parental-controls/).  However I'm not sure how to set this up for the Cellular side of data.  Is this possible, and if so how?

iPhone: 5

iOS: 6.1

Comment: currently not possible for cellular.